# Não consigo inserir na tabela sqlServer dados float quando eles são maiores que 1000

Tags: c#, sql-server

Eu não estou conseguindo inserir variaveis double quando elas são maiores que 1,000.00 por conta da vírgula que apare e assim o sql reconhece que estou tentando inserir dois dados, ja tentei usar o método replace(",","."), porém não deu certo.

```
     if (txtDesconto.Text == string.Empty)
                    {
                        preco = preco - 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        preco -= desconto;
                    }

                    string precoStr = preco.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
                    precoStr.Replace(",", "");

                    Conexao conexao = new Conexao();

                    var escolha = MessageBox.Show("O cliente efetuou o pagamento de " + preco.ToString("c") + " ?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                    if (escolha == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        conexao.conectar();
                        int insere = conexao.executar($"INSERT INTO Vendas(data, carro, placa, idCliente, pago, formaPagamento, valorCobrado) VALUES('{dataAmericanFormat}','{venda.carro}','{venda.placa}','{venda.idCliente}', 1, '{venda.formaPagamento}', {precoStr})  ");
                        conexao.desconectar();

                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Se você está armazenando um valor monetário, faria mais sentido alterar o tipo da coluna no banco de dados de **FLOAT** para **MONEY**. Isto eliminaria a necessidade de usar o *replace* que você está tentando fazer funcionar.

Experimenta o seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE Vendas
ALTER COLUMN valorCobrado MONEY;
```

Comment: Ok, faz muito sentindo o que voce disse e com certeza funcionaria, porém fazer isso daria alguma interferencia nos dados que ja estão salvos?

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

`preco.Valor.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Replace(",",".")`

Lembrando que pode ter problema caso o formato da moeda seja diferente de `PT-BR`, e ainda o próprio SQL Server pode ser configurado para um formato diferente.

Comment: Uso esta linha preco.Valor.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Replace(",",".") para ele salvar os valores assim 200.00 e nao assim 200,00. Mas tem como voce me mostrar como configuro o formato do sql

Comment: Este é o formato correto e padrão SQL, melhor deixar assim e adpitar sua aplicação para formatar o valor quando for consultar.

Comment: Sim isso eu ja faço porém quando eu vou inserir um valor que tenha vírgla ele nao insere